# Script to remove multiple registry keys for graphics adapter

Tags: for-loop, cmd, findstr

The goal is to create a batch file which will remove registry entries for multiple versions of a graphics card driver. It should search the HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video registry key and subkeys for the manufacturer name and write the results to a list or set multiple variables and then delete each one.

Here is my original script which seemed to work ok.

```
:loop reg
for /f "delims=\, tokens=6" %%r in ('reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video /s /f atikmdag') do set rVAR=%%r
for %%r in (%rVAR%) do reg delete HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Video\%%r /f
if not exist "reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video /s /f atikmdag" goto xfiles
goto loop reg

:xfiles
rest of script
```

The variable %%r would be the GUID of the graphics card e.g. {3662D7D0-8848-4091-9116-06D253535481}

The problem is I need to remove registry entries for more than one driver version and the search string "atikmdag" would not return all the results.

I tried this
        reg query HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video /s /v DriverDesc /f "ati"

But it returns all existing entries for 'DriverDesc' and not just the ones that have "ati" in the data field. I think maybe the /s overrides the /f, I'm not sure.

TIA for any help.
-M